# store elemnts back to an array in shell script

Tags: arrays, shell

Could you help me on but how can i put back each element I have read from an array into another array through iteration ?

Like in first iteration I read 11.11.11-1 and I need to put it into another array in first index

Second iteration I read 22.22.22-2 and I need to put it into another array in second index

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I read your question correctly, a test case would be:

```
declare -a readarray
declare -a another
readarray=(11.11.11-1,22.22.22-2,33.33.33-3,44.44.44-4)
num=${#readarray[@]}

for ((i=0; i < num; i++))
do
    another[$i]=${readarray[$i]}
done

echo "${another[@]}"
```

You don't say which shell you are using, I have assumed `bash`.